# Do not render table row checkboxes when collection count is zero with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have to display a list of items using mvc razor.

Each list item has a checkbox.

This checkbox must only be visible/rendered/added to html when the `list.count is > 0`

How would you render/add each item checkbox without using an if clause at every item html?

Comment: You should provide your razor code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to cut down on markup you could use the conditional operator:

`@(list.Any() ? @Html.CheckBox("name", true) : null)`

Comment: But list.Any() would be done for every checkbox that would be bad than its better to use a c# razor clause like @{ var shouldDisplayCheckBox = XXX-logic }

Comment: I was assuming you had a different list for each checkbox,